# replace an element from listadapter with an image

Tags: android, android-layout

So I'm getting the data from my table and put it in a list. The data is showing ok. What I want to do now is: I have a field that display 0 or 1 and based on those values to display in the list 2 images: image 1- value 0; image 2-value 1. This is my code for displaying the data in the list:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = controller.getOld();
            // If users exists in SQLite DB
            if (userList.size() != 0) {
                // Set the User Array list in ListView
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(OldTips.this, userList, R.layout.old_tips, new String[] {
                                "userId", "tara","ora_meci" ,"echipa_acasa","echipa_deplasare","cota","pronostic","explicatii","rezultat"}, new int[] { R.id.userId, R.id.tara , R.id.ora_meci, R.id.echipa_acasa, R.id.echipa_deplasare, R.id.cota,R.id.pronostic,R.id.explicatii,R.id.rezultat});
                final ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                myList.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
```

The fields are: rezultat is showing up in the R.id.rezultat. In the R.layout.old_tips I defined 2 images(A and B) that are invisible. Now I want if rezultat is 1 to make the image A visible and if 0 to make the image B visible.I have no ideea how to obtain this that's why I didn't try anything. I don't have any idea. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not an Android Studio issue. Removing the ANdroid Studio tag

Comment: Use Custom Adapter class

Comment: could you give more details

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Custom Adapter for your list. I recommend you the use of RecyclerView instead of ListView. Have better performance and you can find a lot of tutorials on Internet.

Good luck!